# R function to remove all rows with at leat one NA doesn't work using dplyr

Tags: r, function, dplyr, na

Can you please help me to see why my function is not working? Given this table, `my_df`

```
  sexo edad
1    m   23
2    f   34
3   NA   34
4    f   NA
5    m   33
```

I want to make a function that removes every row with a NA field to use it for different data frames. I made this function:

```
filter_out_nas = function(df){
  vars = names(df)
  for(var in vars){
    print(var)
    df = filter(df, !is.na(var))
  }
  return(df)
}
```

I want the output to look like this:

```
  sexo edad
1    m   23
2    f   34
5    m   33
```

However when I try to use the function on `my_df`, it doesn't do anything:

```
library(dplyr)
my_df = filter_out_nas(m_df)
## returs the same table given above, `my_df` does not change.
```

Thank you very much for your time

Comment: Could you clarify your question? The data you originally provide look exactly the same as your intended result. If I understand you correctly, you want to remove all rows with `NA` values from your dataframe, and store those rows in a new dataframe?

Comment: I'm sorry I've already corrected

Comment: This should work `na.omit(df)`

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't entirely clear on what you wanted, so here are two things that may help.

**First:** remove all rows that have `NA` from your dataframe.

```r
library(tidyr)
df_no_NA <- drop_na(df)
```

**Second:** make a new dataframe with only rows that have `NA`.

```r
library(dplyr)
df_only_NA <- filter_all(df, ~!is.na(.))
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For a base R option here, you could just use `rowSums` with `is.na`:

```
df[rowSums(is.na(df)) == 0, ]

  sexo edad
1    m   23
2    f   34
5    m   33
```

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(sexo=c("m", "f", NA, "f", "m"), edad=c(23,34,34,NA,33))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in a simple way!

```
my_df<- my_df[rowSums(is.na(my_df)) == 0,]
```

And if you have " " (empty) values and NA you can use

```
my_df<- my_df[rowSums(is.na(my_df)| my_df=="") == 0,]
```

Answer (score 0):

the easiest solution should be `na.omit(df)`